# Binary Tree node

Tags: python-3.x

Given the following class;

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, val, left=None, right=None):
        self.val = val
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
```

complete the function

```
def binary_tree_compare(a, b)

# return True if the two binary trees rooted and a and b are equal in value and structure
# return False otherwise

def compare(a, b):
```

Comment: Been trying to solve this code but i need help anyone please. def compare(a,b):

Comment: What code have you written?

Comment: i haven't gotten a solution yet no code yet just the question

Comment: If you don't attempt something on your own, we won't know where you went wrong and cannot correct you, but we won't provide you the whole answer if you don't make any attempt on your own

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
def compare(a, b):
    #check: both nodes empty => same trees
    if(a == None and b == None):
        return True

    #check: only one note empty: different trees
    elif((a == None and b != None) or (a != None and b == None)):
        return False

    #check: node content is the same and all children are the same: same tree
    else:
        return (a.val == b.val) and (compare(a.left, b.left) and compare(a.right, b.right))

tmp_node1 = TreeNode("tmp")
tmp_node2 = TreeNode("tmp")

a = TreeNode("something", left=tmp_node1)
b = TreeNode("something", left=tmp_node2)
c = TreeNode("somthing else")

print(compare(a,b))
print(compare(a,c))
```

Comment: Don't provide the answer without atleast looking at if the OP has attempted something, else he won't understand anything and just copy your code

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`def compare(a, b):
    #check: both nodes empty => same trees
    `enter code here`if(a == None and b == None):
        `enter code here`return True

```
#check: only one note empty: different trees
```

`enter code here` elif((a == None and b != None) or (a != None and b == None)):
        `enter code here`return False

```
#check: node content is the same and all children are the same: same tree
`enter code here`else:
   `enter code here` return (a.val == b.val) and (compare(a.left, b.left) and compare(a.right, b.right))
```